# Capture controller redirect action and load through jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my layout page i have this:

```
<div class="containerSidebar">
    <div class="SidebarSection">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>

<div></div>

<div id="detailView"></div>
```

and when i click the links in my sidebar they open in in the detailView section fine.

When I click a submit button in the detailview it opens in the renderbody section, but i want it to continue opening in the detailview section.

So for example, when it I click submit from this view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestEmployee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Forename, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Forename, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Forename, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It will go to this section in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _NewEmpDetails([Bind(Include = "ID, Forename, Surname")] First NewEmpFirst)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var sessionValues = new MySessionValues();
        sessionValues.Employee = NewEmpFirst;
        Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("_NewEmpSecond");
}
```

I want it to get right up to the RedirectToAction section and a Jquery or Ajax code in the _Layout page to capture the _NewEmp... and dynamically load it in the detaiView section again.

so something like this in a jquery file being called from the _Layout page

```
 $("#detailView").submit(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: form.attr('RedirectToAction'),
                success: function (data) {
                    //At this point I would like to redirect
                    $("#detailView").load($(this).attr("href"));
                },
            });

        });
```

I'm really new to this so if anyone can help that would be great thanks!

Model:

```
namespace OrwellFrontEnd.NewEmp
{
    public class First
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }        
        public string Forename { get; set; }        
        public string Surname { get; set; }       

    }

    public class Second
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstSecond
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class Third
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fourth
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool FullTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

controllername public class TreeviewController : Controller

First page to load _NewEmpDetails > _NewEmpSecond > _NewEmpThird > _NewEmpFourth

Comment: First of all the `div` will not have a submit action whereas `form` will have. If you have slight knowledge on `JsonResult` then you can achieve this.

Comment: The form submits fine though? the only issue is I can't open the next partialview in the partial area.

Comment: That submit is happening because of your `input type = submit`. To load a different partial view you need to modify your code alot. Care to give more details I might help you.

Comment: It loads the correct partial view, the only issue is it loads it as a full view in the renderbody section of the layout page where as I want to stop that action and load it in the detailView section with something like this:

$("#detailView").load($(this).attr("href"));

What information/code would best help you? I'll gladly provide it.

looking for something that will allow the submit, the session variable to be updated, then capture the partialview to be loaded and load it in the detail View section

Comment: Your not cancelling the standard submit. Your code as shown will do the ajax call but then immediately do a standard submit and redirect.

Comment: I understand, but I can't work out how to postback, update the session variable, capture the redirect url cancel the controller loading it and load it through Ajax or jquery  into the view Detial section...

Comment: You script does not make sense. `$("#detailView")` is a `<div>` which does not have a `.submit()` event. `url: form.attr('RedirectToAction'),` will result in `url: null` (your div does not have an attribute named `RedirectToAction`. Like wise `$(this).attr("href")`

Answer (score 0):

So it might go like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("StoreName","TreeviewController",FormMethod.Post, new {id="frmStoreDetails"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestEmployee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Forename, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Forename, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="txtForeName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Forename, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="txtSurName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="javascript:SubmitForm();" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Note:** In the Html.BeginForm I have mentioned `ControllerName`, Please change it to whatever controllerName where you are going to Write `StoreName` Action.

This will be in your controller:

**Note:** I assume that in your session you are storing FirstName and LastName and so in the model, assuming that your model will contain FirstName and LastName attribute, I will just bind FirstName and LastName and send it through ajax to your JsonResult action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult StoreName(UserDataModel model)
{
     bool valid=false; //Just for safety check
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var sessionValues = new MySessionValues();
        sessionValues.Employee = model.FirstName;
        Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;
        valid=true;
    }
    return Json(new {result=valid});
}
```

Write your form Submit in js as below:

```
function SubmitForm()
{
      var valid=false;
      $("#frmStoreDetails").on("submit",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if($("#txtForeName").val()!="" && $("#txtSurName").val()!="")//Validation
            {
                 valid=true;
            }
            if(valid)
            {
                   model : {
                         'FirstName':$("#txtForeName").val(),
                         'LastName':$("#txtSurName").val()

                   };
                   $.ajax({
                       url:'/TreeviewController/StoreName',
                       type: 'POST',
                       dataType:'JSON',
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       data:JSON.stringify(model),
                       success:function(data){
                              if(data.result)
                              {
                                  $('#detailView').load("/TreeviewController/GetNewEmpSecond");
                              }
                              else
                              { 
                                  //display Error in some div
                              }
                       },
                       error:function(data){
                              //display error
                       }
                  });
            }
            $("#" + form).unbind('submit');
            return false;
      });
}
```

Write One more `PartialViewResult` Action in your controller with name `GetNewEmpSecond` as below

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetNewEmpSecond()
{
        //do whatever you want here
        return PartialView('_NewEmpSecond');
}
```

That's it.. It will load your partial view in specified div.

Let me know if any doubts.

**EDIT:**

As per your comments **The _NewEmpSeconed which I want to load next uses model @model OrwellFrontEnd.NewEmp.Second** I believe that you need to pass your model back to calling partial view and that is why you are getting that exception. So just make changes in `GetNewEmpSecond()` PartialViewResult Action as below"

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetNewEmpSecond()
{
        //do whatever you want here
        OrwellFrontEnd.NewEmp.Second model = new OrwellFrontEnd.NewEmp.Second();

        //Fill model values
        return PartialView('_NewEmpSecond',model); //Send your model with partial view. I hope you are receiving it in the Partial View.
}
```

**Note**: I've changed the controllerName wherever required as given by you.
and regarding your further steps you can just follow the same process to load other partial views. Hope it is cleared.

Comment: Hi and thanks very much for this. I'm getting an invalid model message for the Ajax section.  The _NewEmpSeconed which I want to load next uses model @model OrwellFrontEnd.NewEmp.Second

This was the reason I was using session variables.  sorry i didn't include that.  I load a serious of partial views each with its own model to build up a data set to then insert into a database split into their own tables

Comment: return PartialView('_NewEmpSecond',model); - "returns Too many characters in character literal"

How do I pass the values back from the Ajax script to the next view to store in a session variable?

Is there a way to just update a session variable in the Ajax script as I want ot go through multiple stages?

Comment: Can you post screen shot of exception... regarding your second question if you go through what answer I have given you can see that I've passed model values to controller through Ajax... same way you can achieve for other partial views.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could not perform Response.Redirect for the Ajax request. But you can inform the requester to reload from the new url. Hence changing the below code in controller action method makes sense in your code

```
public ActionResult ActionName(Type model)
{
  //do something
  //return RedirectToAction("_NewEmpSecond");// not possible
  return Json(new{status='success', redirectUrl='/Action2/Param1'})
}
```

Also refactor your ajax call

```
$("#detailView").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();// do not perform default submit of form
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: " ",
                url: form.attr('RedirectToAction'),
                success: function (data) {
                   if(data.status==='success'){
                    //At this point I would like to redirect
                     $("#detailView").load(data.redirectUrl);
                    }
                },
            });

        });
```